# Fail to self-update composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been using **composer** for about a month now. And then one day **composer** shows me this message:

> Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is
>   recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer
>   self-update" to get the latest version.

I've installed *composer* globally as per the documentation.

```
which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

Running **sudo composer self-update** gives me this message:

> /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory

I've checked **/usr/bin/env**
with this command:

```
whereis /usr/bin/env
env: /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/X11/env /usr/share/man/man1/env.1.gz
```

my php version:

```
PHP 5.5.1 (cli) (built: Jul 26 2013 19:50:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

It seems like **/usr/bin/env** in fact exists.

I'm using **ubuntu 12.04LTS**.

**Update**

```
strace sudo composer self-update 2>&1 | grep open

open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/en_PH/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_PH/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Btw, i'm using xampp installed at **/opt**
and **php** is in my **PATH**.

```
echo $PATH

/home/chanhxc/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/chanhxc/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/lampp/bin:/home/chanhxc/pear/bin:/home/chanhxc/.composer/vendor/bin:/opt/lampp/bin
```

Comment: It looks like you have no PHP installed. Check `php --version`.

Comment: i have one. I have in fact been using composer for about a month now.

Comment: i'm gonna update my question to show my php versoin

Comment: Do you call `composer self-update` with root privileges ?

Comment: What gives you `env php`?

Comment: yeah, i run it with sudo privileges. I've posted it in my question.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I've tried `env php` 
but nothing is happening, it just runs without any output.

Comment: @noobieAtFirst Meaning it works :) (php is installed and env can find it). Hard to say what causes the composer problem.. Works for me.. Can you execute `strace sudo composer self-update 2>&1 | grep open` and add the output to your question? (Would like to see which files being accessed)

Comment: @hek2mgl, thanks for your response, but still doesn't answer my question. :)

Comment: @hek2mgl, i've already updated my answer

Comment: is this all output? (Can't believe). Is php in `root`'s `$PATH` too?

Comment: @hek2mgl, yes that's all the output.
Is there something wrong?

Comment: @noobieAtFirst Sorry, the missing output was my fault. Execute the command again as root. (you won't need sudo then). Again, is php in `root`'s `$PATH` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl, isn't sudo using the privileges of root?
I'm pretty new to linux. I maybe wrong with this.
how would if it's in the `root`'s `$PATH`. 
Can i simply run `echo $PATH`

Comment: Try `sudo su` .. Then `env php -v` does it work?

Comment: @hek2mgl, i've executed those and the output is `env: php: No such file or directory`

Comment: @hek2mgl, thanks a lot for your help. I've already fixed the problem.
It seems like there's an issue with composer with symlinking php executable using xampp.
The answer below solved my problem.
Again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error message:

> /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory

tells you that `php` is not found, i.e. `php-cli` is not installed or php command is not in your `PATH` environment variable.

So you need to install (`sudo apt-get install php5-cli`) or put it in you PATH:

```
vim ~/.bashrc

PATH=$PATH:/path/to/php-cli/bin
export PATH
```

**UPDATE**

Accordingly to [Composer with XAMPP for Linux](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1438) issue symlinking php executable should solve your problem:

`ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: i'm using xampp
i have php in my path. 
i've updated my question to show the PATH env variable.

php is located at `/opt/lampp/bin` directory

Comment: The problem is: `Is php in root's path?` Asked that multiple times :)

Comment: `ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php` worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this solution will work if you have xampp

```
ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
```

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same issue (on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server). My solution was to switch to root user, instead of sudo:

```
sudo su
/usr/local/bin/composer self-update
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same solution in Centos https://stackoverflow.com/a/31945422/2400373

```
   # /usr/local/php/bin/php -v
   #  /usr/local/php/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer self-update
```

Regards